# Find radius of convergence, and then test the endpoints to determine the interval of convergence.

Tags: calculus

> Consider $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{x}{5}\right)^k$$

In class we had an extremely brief discussion on this topic, and so I still have many questions on how to start these problems. It seems that there are many steps involved, but most of them are tied into the convergence/divergence tests. So I was hoping that by seeing the work of this simple problem, I'd be able to work on the harder problems on the homework.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence

Comment: You could also notice that it is the sum of terms in geometric progression.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{x^{k+1}5^k}{5^{k+1}x^k}\right|<1\\
\implies |x|<5\\
\implies x\in (-5,5),\text{ radius of convergence: }10.$$
You can test the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

A necessary, albeit not sufficient, condition for an infinite series to converge is that its general term tends to $0$ as the iterator tends to infinity. So $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\bigg(\dfrac x5\bigg)^k=0$, which can only happen for $|x|<5$, otherwise the limit is either $\pm1$, for $x=\pm5$, or $\pm\infty$, for $|x|>5$. Now, since $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}t^k=\frac{1-t^n}{1-t}$ , then, for $n\to\infty$, we have $t^n\to0$ for $|t|<1$, so $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\bigg(\dfrac x5\bigg)^k=\frac1{1-\tfrac x5}-1$, which clearly converges for all $x\neq5$. Now, $|x|<5$ is the same as saying $x\in(-5,5)$, and since all numbers on this interval possess this property, then the convergence radius is $5-(-5)=5+5=10$.